# T-SQL Debugging Logon Failure

Tags: t-sql, debugging, sql-server-2008

**Server Info:**
Windows Server 2008, SQL Server Standard 2008 (64-bit)

I recently upgraded to SQL 2008 and was interested in trying out T-SQL Debugging.  Initally encountered some firewall issues, but after disabling my workstation's Windows Firewall and having TCP port 135 and UDP 4500/500 opened up by the IT group I got a little further.

Now I get the error message:

*Unable to start T-SQL Debugging. Could not connect to computer 'servername'. Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.*

My workstation and server are on different domains and I use Windows authentication to connect to the machine.  My account is sysadmin and connects to the server fine in SSMS.  The SQL Server service is running as a different service-level account.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the same error message. My configuration, however, is different. I am connected from Management Studio 2008 with an SQL user to a SQL Server 2008 instance.

I user a sniffer ([Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)) to monitor IP traffic en saw the following:

> - DCERPC Bind: call_id: 5 IRemUnknown2 V0.0, NTLMSSP_NEGOTIATE
> - DCERPC Bind_ack: call_id: 5, NTLMSSP_CHALLENGE accept max_xmit:
>     5840 max_recv: 5840
> - DCERPC AUTH3: call_id: 5, NTLMSSP_AUTH, User:
>     \
> - IRemUnknown2   RemRelease request[Malformed Packet]
> - TCP    49914 > mapper-mapethd [ACK] Seq=247 Ack=526 Win=63846 Len=0
> - DCERPC Fault: call_id: 5 ctx_id: 0 status: nca_s_fault_access_denied

Note: my actual domain and user have been replaced by  and , respectively.

Maybe, this can help you to get more detailled information.

At this point, I am stuck. I tried to give this domain user access to the server, but do not have permission to do so. Also, I am not sure if this is needed, because I connect using an SQL user.